# I can't seem to get my a button to work to submit info on my login screen

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

I am hoping someone can help me i have been looking for a solution and i can't find one anywhere. when i run the program i fill in all the input boxes and press Log in but nothing happens. at this point i just need to get to the stage where the alert with "pass" works here is my code: 
`

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title> Login </title>

    <script>     
        var io = 0
        var Name = [""];
        var stayLocation = [""];
        var outOfTown = [""];



        function click(){
            var serch = document.getElementById("id").value; 
            var user = document.getElementById("user");
            var pass = document.getElementById("pass");
            alert(pass)  
        }

    </script>   

</head>

<body>
<h1>Log In</h1>
Id:<input id="id" type="text" name="ID"> <br />
Username:<input id="user" type="text" name="Username">  <br />
Password:<input id="pass" type="text" name="Password"> 
<br /> <br />
<input type="button" name="Log In" value="Log In" onclick=click()>



</body>
```

`

Comment: why don't you use a real form (with a `form` tag around all your inputs)  and a submit button?

Comment: it's because the function name "click", just change it to another name it will work. Besides that, it's highly recommended to use "form" element to wrap all these input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your function name click() to something else...